# Differential equations and groups

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

Consider the following linear ODE

$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} =A \vec{x}$$
where $A$ is an invertible matrix. This is the motivation of the question.

I wondering whether $\{e^{At}\mid t\geq 0\}$ is a group? In case yes, it is a Lie group? It is a compact group?

Moreover, does it hold that

$$ cl(<A>)= \{e^{At}\mid t\geq 0\}$$
where $cl(<A>)$ is the closure of the group generated by $A$ (wrt the Euclidean topology)?

Answer (score 0):

Is obviously a *semigroup*. The multiplicative inverse of $e^{At}$ is $e^{-(At)}=e^{A(-t)}$. The *group* is
$$\{e^{At}\,\vert\, t\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Isn't compact because is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.